# Parsing complex error objects with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm having a problem figuring out how to properly process a complex error object using RestKit. All the examples I've seen detail how to map a nested string of arbitrary depth to the NSError *errorMessage property. For example:

```
{
  meta: {status: 406},
  error: {message: "email is invalid"}
}
```

I've seen people talk about using a key mapping of "error.message" -> "errorMessage", but I want all the information in the error response. For example, I want to access the entire error_object dictionary in the following 406 error response:

```
{
  meta: {code: 406},
  error_object: {attributes: {email: ["is invalid"]}}
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm currently using [RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:... . Since the failure callback only takes NSError, I understand that I may need to use some other mechanism of RestKit to accomplish the behavior I want.